# What is a Corny Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is based on the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463).</sub>

---

If a word follows a certain rule, then I call it a Corny Word™.

Use the example word lists below to find the rule. Each word can be tested for whether it is a Corny Word™ without depending on other words in these lists.

| Corny Word™ | Not Corny Word™ |
| --- | --- |
| CORN | COB |
| THROUGH | THOUGHT |
| ANTONYM | SYNONYM |
| CHRISTMAS | CAROL |
| EARMUFFS | HEADPHONES |
| REMOTE | CONTROLLER |
| CLARINET | PIANO |
| ELEPHANT | RHINOCEROS |

To analyze, here's a CSV version:

```
Corny Word™, Not Corny Word™
CORN, COB
THROUGH, THOUGHT
ANTONYM, SYNONYM
CHRISTMAS, CAROL
EARMUFFS, HEADPHONES
REMOTE, CONTROLLER
CLARINET, PIANO
ELEPHANT, RHINOCEROS
```

I can add more examples if necessary.

Comment: You're more than welcome to copy the style from one of the other versions to mimic the appearance of these puzzles! (Go into edit and grab the content, and then apply your words)

Comment: You might want to add more examples. Most of these puzzles are only solvable because there are at least 15-20 examples on each side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A corny word follows one rule:

> The word, when written in upper-case, contains exactly two enclosed spaces (Such as the "loop" of the letter R or the "triangle" of the letter A).

All examples above fit this rule. Non-corny words shown in the examples

> either have zero, one, or 3+ enclosed spaces.

As far as the reason to be a "Corny" word, in particular, my best guess is that

> There is a game called "Corn Hole" in which players throw bags at a hole on the opposite side of the field. Two "holes" in the game, two "holes" in the letters of a corny word.

Comment: Misread the second bit. Not sure why that fits the word corny though

Comment: @Mordechai where do you see it *not* counting? Mister B did not specify all of them ("such as...")

Comment: @Mordechai Please try not to reveal the answer in a comment when the answerer has nicely gone to the effort of spoiler-tagging the answer.